# Инициализация случайного количества объектов

Tags: c#

Как мне создать случайное количество объектов определённого класса?

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int cars = rnd.Next(2, 10);
for (int i = 0; i < cars; i++)
{
   car car{i} = new car(); // Вот тут нужно создать объект, имеющий определённое имя, основанное на переменной i. К примеру car1,car2,car3,car56
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мсье слышал про массивы?

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int carsCount = rnd.Next(2, 10);
car[] cars = new car[carsCount];
for (int i = 0; i < carsCount; i++) {
    car[i] = new car();
}
```

**Обновление**

Потому что `car` - ссылочный тип. Создавая массив объектов ссылочного типа вы не инициализируете эти объекты автоматически. Зачастую это может оказаться невозможным из-за отсутствия у класса конструктора по умолчанию. Создавая массив объектов ссылочного типа вы заполняете его ссылками на `null`. Поэтому элементы массивов ссылочных типов инициализируются вручную. Примитивные же типы (`int`, `double` и т. д.) можно инициализировать значениями по умолчанию (нулями, например).

Comment: >car[] cars = new car[carsCount];
>car[i] = new car();
То есть каждый элемент массива, состоящего из объектов класса car нужно ещё дополнительно определять, как car?

Почему же тогда массив из чисел не нужно каждый раз так определять.
Типа
int[] a = new int[5]
for...
a[i] = new int();

?

Comment: Потому что `car` - ссылочный тип. Создавая массив объектов ссылочного типа вы не инициализируете эти объекты автоматически. Зачастую это может оказаться невозможным из-за отсутствия у класса конструктора по умолчанию. Создавая массив объектов ссылочного типа вы заполняете его ссылками на `null`. Поэтому элементы массивов ссылочных типов инициализируются вручную. Примитивные же типы (`int`, `double` и т. д.) можно инициализировать значениями по умолчанию (нулями, например).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.